# Adding a label to a Point on map in ArcGIS

Tags: java, arcgis, label

I have static points on a map.
I use this code to draw them:

```
point = GeometryEngine.project(longitude, latitude, mapSR); 
pointGraphic = new Graphic(point, symbol);
graphicsLayer.addGraphic(pointGraphic);
```

The point is drawed on the map.

Now I want to add a label to it - show under the drawn point it's longitude and latitude.
I can do it using text adding, but then when I resize the map, the text placement changes.
I want to put it like a label - let's say on the bottom right from the point.
I want it to be sensitive for zooming, and binded to the Point.

I read about dinamic labels, but it seems very complex for such a simple request.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this an ArcGIS map, or a JavaScript map using the ArcGIS JavaScript API?

Comment: The question was tagged with Java, so I'm guessing this is for the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Java.

Comment: Yes, what Gary said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual graphics don't have labels, but you can create two graphics with the same geometry. Use your current symbol for one of them. For the other graphic, use a [`TextSymbol`](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/api-reference/), calling `setOffsetX(float)` and `setOffsetY(float)` to place it the way you want.

Comment: Awesome! There are buttons for that! :-)